# Inequality involving a summation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Is it possible to say for arbitrary real numbers $a_n$ and $b_n$

$$\left(\sum_{n=1}^K (a_n - b_n)\right)^2 \leq C_K\sum_{n=1}^K (a_n^2 + b_n^2).$$

For some $C_K > 0$ depending on $K$. If so what can be said about $C_K$?

Comment: The following is true $(a_n-b_n)^2 \leq a_n^2 +b_n^2$

Comment: Hint: Triangle Inequality. I think this is covered in chapter 1 of Baby Rudin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, you can find $$\left(\sum_{n=1}^K (a_n - b_n)\right)^2 =\left(\sum_{n=1}^K \frac{a_n - b_n}{\sqrt{a_n^2 + b_n^2}} \sqrt{a_n^2 + b_n^2}\right)^2 \leq\sum_{n=1}^K \left(1-\frac{2a_nb_n}{a_n^2+b_n^2}\right) \sum_{n=1}^K (a_n^2 + b_n^2).$$
Then, since $-\frac{2a_nb_n}{a_n^2+b_n^2}\leq 1$, you find
$$\left(\sum_{n=1}^K (a_n - b_n)\right)^2 \leq 2K \sum_{n=1}^K (a_n^2 + b_n^2).$$
You can see that $C_K=2K$ is an "optimal" constant since the last inequality becomes an equality for $a_n=1$ and $b_n=-1$ for all $n$.

Comment: You're welcome. Quick remark: if you add the condition that both sequences are nonnegative, the optimal constant becomes $C_K=K$.